# Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

After upgrading my ASP.NET 5 API to 1.0.0-rc1-update1 I get the exception shown below.

Startup runs through just fine.  The exception gets logged when I try to call upon the API.

**Startup:**

I have stripped down `Startup` to the bare essentials but still the problem persists.

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

**project.json**:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.6",
      "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.22",
      "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "WindowsAzure.Storage": "5.0.2",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
    }
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
            }
        }
    },
}
```

**Exception thrown in Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel:**

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeModelBinder.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerActionArgumentBinder.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerActionArgumentBinder.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerActionArgumentBinder.d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__51.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.InnerAttributeRoute.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet.RequestTrackingMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Http.Frame.d__79.MoveNext()

Comment: Startup doesn't make sense here. Could you please post WebAPI function that creates this exception?